# Can't figure out how to make a generator from a generator

Tags: f#, fscheck

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make fscheck generators WITHOUT using the `gen` workflow syntax and assume there must be a good way to do it. I end up with a nested `Gen<Gen<...` and want a flattened version. With `option` I'd use `Option.bind` to eliminate the nesting. With `seq` I'd use `SelectMany`. But I don't see that kind of method appear in the `Gen` module.

```
// return a Gen<char list> as expected
// first makes a random number from 5 to 8
// and then creates a random list of characters that long
let randomListLengths =
    gen {
        let! len = Gen.choose(5,8)
        let! item = Gen.elements ['a';'b';'c'] |> Gen.listOfLength len
        return item
    }

// return a Gen<Gen<char list>>
let anotherWayThatDoesNotWork =
    Gen.choose(5, 8)
    |> Gen.map (fun len -> Gen.elements['a';'b';'c'] |> Gen.listOfLength len)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `>>=` operator:

```ml
let randomListLengths =
    Gen.choose(5,8)
    >>= (fun len -> Gen.elements ['a';'b';'c'] |> Gen.listOfLength len)
```

Comment: Great thanks! For discoverability, shouldn't there be a Gen.bind like Option.bind and Result.bind?

Comment: Yes, perhaps. You're the first to ask for it :) that said bind has probably become more "known" over the past few years.